# Error generating swig interface for library which overrides std::exception

Tags: c++, swig

I'm trying to generate a swig interface for a library that has a class which inherits from `std::exception`. I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's a simple example. Code for `mylib.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include <exception>

class CustomException : public std::exception
{

};
```

Here's the code for `mylib.i`:

```
%module mylib
 %{
 #include "mylib.h"
 %}

/*
Run without anything:
mylib.h:5: Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'std::exception'. Ignored.
*/

/*
Run with: %include <exception>
mylib.i:11: Error: Unable to find 'exception'
*/

/*
Run with: %include exception.i 
mylib.h:5: Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'std::exception'. Ignored.
*/

%include "mylib.h"
```

As you can see in the comments in `mylib.i`, swig seems to have a hard time figuring out what `std::exception` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%include <std_except.i>`:

```
%module test
%include <std_except.i>
%inline %{
class CustomException : public std::exception
{
};
%}
```